# Loading with ngInclude into multiple DOM locations

Tags: angularjs

I'm building an app in AngularJS where the user creates some app state, then there are a number of different ways to render it.  (For a lame example, let's say they're going to enter three numbers, and then they can choose to render them into a line chart or a pie chart.)

Each rendering type lives in a different HTML file, and I'm letting the user choose a renderer with a <select> which drives the src for an ng-include to load the different renderers. This works fine, so far.

Now, some rendering modes have additional controls; for example, the pie chart might have a "3D" checkbox. Different renderers will have entirely distinct controls. So I want these included files to also create controls for customizing their presentation.

Here's my question: how do I load a single file and let it create its additional control in one spot in the DOM while putting its main content into another spot in the DOM? The additional control cannot appear adjacent to the rendered content in the DOM: it goes in an entirely different location.

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/1RXVVu?p=preview. I would like, in a.html and b.html, to be able to instantiate their popup controls in the DOM above the <hr>, while having their textual content below the <hr>. (While it would be possible in the example to just put an hr tag in each of a.html and b.html, the real DOM structure is much more complex and doesn't afford that.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a directive to move the element to another container. Here is what I changed from your plunker.

I added jQuery and the directive:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

    app.directive('myContainer', [function() {
      return {
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          angular.element(attrs.myContainer).replaceWith(elem);
          //angular.element(attrs.myContainer).html(elem);
          //angular.element(attrs.myContainer).appendTo(elem);
          //etc...
        }
      };
    }]);
  })();
</script>
```

I added a container above the hr:

```
<div id="#container"></div>
```

I specified the directive attribute with the container id in a.html and b.html:

```
<select ng-model="color" ng-options="c for c in ['red', 'blue']" data-my-container="#container"></select>
```

The container id (or selector) could come from the model dynamically.

Comment: This was great, thanks, and led me to the solution. Below I added links to my final implementation, just for the record.

Answer (score 0):

I worked the Plunker into a complete solution here: http://tdierks.github.io/angular-element-mover/, code is here: https://github.com/tdierks/angular-element-mover.

The critical directive is:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('controlMover', []);
  app.directive('moveTo', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.appendTo(angular.element(attrs.moveTo));
        scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
          elem.remove();
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
})();
```

One note: I had to listen for $destroy events on the scope to remove the moved DOM element when the pane changes. I haven't yet checked to be sure there's no leakage here, but it's a concern.

Random other things I ran into, for the education of others:

- JQuery needs to be loaded *before* Angular.
- This app extension with the directive needs to be named on the ng-app directive in the HTML.